# ORACLE UPPER applied to IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, uppercase, in-clause

I have an Oracle query in which I would like to apply the UPPER function to all the values in the IN condition, instead of explicitly calling UPPER on each value, ex.

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b IN UPPER(v1, v2, v3, v4);
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE b IN (UPPER(v1), UPPER(v2), UPPER(v3), UPPER(v4));
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Where do `v1` through `v4` come from?  Can they be converted to uppercase prior to the query?

Comment: are v1,..,v4 in a mixed case? Just an idea to use LOWER(B)

Answer (score 2):

You can do (almost) that by turning off case sensitivity:

```
alter session set NLS_COMP=ANSI;
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;

select * from A where B in (v1, v2, v3, v4)
```